# Deallocating boost shared pointers and clr_scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, wpf, visual-c++, boost, c++-cli

I am working on a WPF project which wraps a legacy C++ code base using MS C++ / CLI. We have several ref classes in the CLI layer that have variables declared like this.

```
clr_scoped_ptr<boost::shared_ptr<Bend>> m_bendTool;
clr_scoped_ptr<boost::shared_ptr<ShapeRings>> m_rings;
```

And like this as well without using boost

```
clr_scoped_ptr<Vector3D> m_bendAxis;
clr_scoped_ptr<Vector3D> m_upVector;
```

The REF classes are being instantiated in C# WPF UserControl classes, problem is I need the native memory to be cleaned up when the WPF control goes away. However it doesn't seem to ever get cleaned up. The C# code calls the dispose method on the C++/CLI class. In there I've tried doing something like this but not sure its actually freeing memory.

```
AductAbductModController::~AductAbductModController()
{
    if (m_bendTool)
    {
        m_bendTool.reset();
    }
    if (m_rings)
    {
        m_rings.reset();
    }
    m_bendAxis.Dispose();
    m_upVector.Dispose();
}
```